# Using a @Parameter for different search options

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have the following query that works as expected, but I'm needing to change it slightly.

I have a @SearchType parameter that can have one of the following values:

- ALL
- FirstName
- LastName
- VerificationCode
- IdentifierValue

Depending on what is passed it should only do the below part of the query for the relevant option specified.

For example, if FirstName is passed it should only search off the FirstName field, but if ALL is passed, it should search on All.

```
                SELECT *
                FROM #SearchWords s
                WHERE (c.FirstName LIKE CONCAT (s.Word,'%'))
                    OR (c.LastName LIKE CONCAT(s.Word,'%'))
                    OR (c.VerificationCode LIKE CONCAT(s.Word,'%'))
                    OR (CI.IdentifierValue LIKE CONCAT(s.Word,'%'))
```

Anyone aware of how this could be achieved?

```
SELECT
    C.ClientID, 
    C.FirstName,
    C.LastName,
    C.FullName, 
    C.DateOfBirth,
    CI.IdentifierValue,
    G.GenderName, 
    G.GenderIcon,
    C.VerificationCode,
    C.LastVisitDate,
    CV.VisitID,
    CS.ClientSanctionID
FROM 
    Client C
INNER JOIN LookUp.Gender G on
    C.GenderID = G.GenderID
LEFT JOIN ClientIdentifier CI on
    C.ClientID = CI.ClientID and
    IdentifierTypeID = @IdentifierTypeID
LEFT JOIN vwClientVisiting CV on
    C.ClientID = CV.ClientID
LEFT JOIN ClientSanction CS on
    C.ClientID = CS.ClientID and
    CS.IsActive = 1
WHERE
    (
        EXISTS( -- if we have words
                SELECT *
                FROM #SearchWords s
                WHERE (c.FirstName LIKE CONCAT (s.Word,'%'))
                    OR (c.LastName LIKE CONCAT(s.Word,'%'))
                    OR (c.VerificationCode LIKE CONCAT(s.Word,'%'))
                    OR (CI.IdentifierValue LIKE CONCAT(s.Word,'%'))
            )
        OR @SearchWordCount = 0 --if we don't have words
    )
    AND DateOfBirth BETWEEN ISNULL(@LowerDate,DateOfBirth) AND ISNULL(@UpperDate,DateOfBirth)
```

Comment: inside each of your predicates just add - and @serchType = appropriateValue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past, I've used something similar to the below.

For each of the four clauses it checks that @SearchType applies to that clause (@SearchText = 'FirstName' or 'ALL'), AND that the 'word' matches (c.FirstName LIKE s.Word).

This should cover you :)

```
SELECT *
FROM #SearchWords s
WHERE 
    ((@SearchType = 'FirstName' OR @SearchText = 'ALL') AND c.FirstName LIKE CONCAT (s.Word,'%'))
    OR ((@SearchType = 'LastName' OR @SearchText = 'ALL') AND c.LastName LIKE CONCAT(s.Word,'%'))
    OR ((@SearchType = 'VerificationCode' OR @SearchText = 'ALL') AND c.VerificationCode LIKE CONCAT(s.Word,'%'))
    OR ((@SearchType = 'IdentifierValue' OR @SearchText = 'ALL') AND CI.IdentifierValue LIKE CONCAT(s.Word,'%'))
```

Comment: Thanks, worked a treat and is the simpler option here.

Answer (score 2):

You could try some like this.

Add each `@SearchType = [Your desire SearchType]` on your `where` clause and use `OR` join them.

```
SELECT *
FROM #SearchWords s
WHERE 
    (@SearchType = 'FirstName' AND c.FirstName LIKE CONCAT (s.Word,'%'))
    OR (@SearchType = 'LastName' AND c.LastName LIKE CONCAT(s.Word,'%'))
    OR (@SearchType = 'VerificationCode' AND c.VerificationCode LIKE CONCAT(s.Word,'%'))
    OR (@SearchType = 'IdentifierValue' AND CI.IdentifierValue LIKE CONCAT(s.Word,'%'))
    OR (@SearchType = 'ALL' AND (
                                  c.FirstName LIKE CONCAT (s.Word,'%') OR 
                                  c.LastName LIKE CONCAT(s.Word,'%') OR 
                                  CI.IdentifierValue LIKE CONCAT(s.Word,'%') OR
                                  CI.VerificationCode LIKE CONCAT(s.Word,'%')
                                ) 
        )
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  I think that each clause in the WHERE should look more like:  `((@SearchType = 'FirstName' OR @SearchType = 'ALL') AND c.FirstName LIKE CONCAT (s.Word,'%'))`

Comment: @user5151179 would you mind posting this as a answer?

Comment: If `@SearchType` = 'ALL', you should include all possibilities. One way to do it is the way user5151179 proposed, the other is to change the last condition to `OR @SearchType = 'ALL' AND (c.FirstName LIKE CONCAT (s.Word,'%') OR  c.LastName LIKE CONCAT(s.Word,'%')...))` (include all options inside)